# Let $X$ be a metric space with $\{p\} = E \subset X.$ Does $E$ have limit points?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $X$ be a metric space with $E = \{p\} \subset X$.
Let $N_r(p)$ stand for a neighborhood of $p$ of radius $r.$
So we have $N_r(p) \cap E = \{p\}$ meaning $p$ is not a limit point.
But limit points can be outside $E$ so we must check every point $q \in X$ a well.
By definition of limit points, $N_k(q) \cap E \ne \emptyset$ must hold for all $k > 0$ for $q$ to be a limit point. So if we can find some $k > 0$ s.t. $N_k(q) \cap E = \emptyset,$ then we can say that no point in $X$ is a limit point of $E. $ So let $0 < k < d(p, q).$ Then $N_k(q)$ contains all points of $X$ that bunch up around $q$ in a radius that is smaller than the distance from $p$ to $q$ meaning $p$ is outside the cluster of points $N_k(q).$ So, $N_k(q) \cap E = \emptyset.$ Thus, neither $p,$ nor any other point in $X$ is a limit point of $E$ meaning $E$ has no limit points.

Does the above make sense to you?

Comment: No. This is confusing and unclear.  Why does $N_r(p)$ contain only $p$?   What you should do is rewrite, stating your hypotheses first, and then posing your question.

Comment: @kimchilover, each neighborhood around $p$ only contains one element
of $E,$ which is $p$ itself.

Comment: Where does it say so in the problem statement?  I don't want to squander my ESP powers on this problem.  If I'm perplexed, it is possible other readers will be perplexed, too.  You should rewrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have all of the right ideas, but the writing is difficult to follow and you misuse a few words here and there. I'll do my best to make improvements without changing the techniques.

We claim that $E$ does not have any limit points. The fact that $p$ is not a limit point of $E$ is seen by noticing that, for every $r>0$ we have $N_r(p)\cap E=\{p\}$. Hence $N_r(p)\cap E$ does not contain a point different from $p$. It remains to show that every $q\in X\setminus E$ is not a limit point of $E$. Given $q\in X\setminus E$, let $k$ be such that $0<k<d(p,q)$. Now $p\not\in N_k(q)$, so that $N_k(p)\cap E = \emptyset$. Hence $q$ is not a limit point of $E$. This completes the proof.

Comment: This proof is just a description of the picture of the whole situation I have in my head. I just wanted to see if I had the right picture. Also, I see I could've used something else instead of "cluster of points $N_k(q)$." That was just meant to be descriptive :) Thanks.