# Understanding analysis/topology proofs

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $X$ be a finite metric space with $\{p\} = E \subset X.$ Does $E$ have interior points?

Proof's given below. But I want to put it in my own words so that I understand it.

[image]

Text below is how I see it. Not very pretty, but as long as it makes sense, it's all good to me.

$N_r(p)$ is a neighborhood of $p$ of radius $r.$
Let $r < $ smallest $q \in X.$ Then $N_r(p)$ contains all points of $X$ that are to the left of the smallest $q$ on the number line meaning all $q \in X$ fall outside $N_r(p).$ For example, if the smallest $q = 1$ and $r = 0.5,$ all points $\ge 1 \ \in X$  are too large to fit in the distance between p and $0.5.$ But the interval within the radius $r$ contains $p$ and probably some other points smaller than $q.$ Since we are only worried about $p$ and $q,$ we ignore all other points $< q$ (that are not $p$). Thus $N_r(p) = \{p\} \subset E$ and so $p$ is interior point of $E.$

Does my interpretation make sense?

edit: Also, I just realized real numbers don't have "thickness" to them so they (however large they are)  fit between $p$ and $0.5$

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}\min\{ q_{1}, \dots, q_{n} \}$ need not be a real number... This is a gross error. The author must mean, if $p = q_{i}$ for some $i$, then $r := \frac{1}{2}\min \{ d(q_{i},q_{j}) \mid i \neq j \}$.

Comment: Suppose the author made a mistake/typo. Like you showed it's easily fixable.  We are not given $X = \mathbb R.$ How do we think about the whole thing with the radius geometrically if we are not in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: even $X =\mathbb{R}$ that choice does not make sense; his point is to show that $p$ is an isolated point. Distance is an abstract thing.

Comment: Consider this following post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2393860/let-x-be-a-metric-space-with-p-e-subset-x-does-e-have-limit-points/2393868#2393868 . There I thought of $X = \mathbb R$ and it worked out. Just a coincidence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are some points you aren't completely understanding here.
First of all, there is no number line involved here, $X$ is an arbitrary set, with some distance function defined on it, specifically, $X$ is not necessarily linearly ordered, so something like "the smallest $q$" doesn't really make sense in this context.

Secondly, if we do assume $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$, or linearly ordered, then $N_r(p)$ contains all the points *whose distance from p* is less than the distance of the nearest $q\in X$ to $p$ (which is probably what you meant).

What we are trying to prove is that $N_r(p)$ contains *no* points besides $p$, meaning that there aren't any points closer to $p$ than $q$. So if

> the interval within the radius $r$ contains $p$ and some other points smaller than $q$

those points would be inside $N_r(p)$, and then $N_r(p)$ *wouldn't* be a neighborhood of $p$ contained in $E$.
Basically, we don't ignore other points in $X$ because we only care about $q$, we ignore them because we specifically chose $q$ such that there *aren't* any other points between them.

Comment: Is the interval of radius $r$ empty?

Comment: the interval of radius $r$ *around $p$* isn't empty, it contains $p$, because the distance between $p$ and itself is $0$.

Comment: Thanks. One more time: the distance of length $r$ is not empty, but we chose $q_i$ such that we ignore everything between $q_i$ and $q_j \ (i \ne j)$ that's less than $r?$

Comment: we didn't choose a $q_i$ per se, we chose $r$ to be less than the distance between $p$ and the nearest $q$. If we take $q_i$ to be the point in $X$ whose distance from $p$ is minimal, then there *are no points* between $p$ and $q_i$.

You seem to be still thinking of $X$ as a subset of $\mathbb R$, instead try thinking of it as points in the plane, or in space ($\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$) and see how that affects your intuition

Comment: One last time. Promise. The distance of length of $r$ around $p$ contains $p$ **only**. The distance of length $r$ between $p$ and the point $q_i$ (point closest to $p$) is empty. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

The statement is indeed meaningless, except in ordered sets.

If $X = \{q_1, \ldots,q_n\}$, and $p \in X$, then there are the distances (which *are* real numbers, so have an order) $d(p,q_1),\ldots,d(p,q_n)$. As $p$ is one of these $q_i$, exactly one of these numbers is $0$, the others are $>0$.

So $r = \frac{1}{2}\min\{d(p, q_i) :q_i \neq p\}$ is well defined (and what the author *should* have written) and $r>0$ (as the minimum is one of the numbers $d(p, q_i) > 0$.

The claim is that $N_r(p) = \{p\}$. Of course $p \in N_r(p)$ always, and if $x \neq p$ then $x = q_i$ for some $q_i$. We took the minimum of *all* $d(p,q_i)$ like that so $\min\{d(p, q_i): q_i \neq p\} \le d(p,q_i)$ so in particular $r < d(p,q_i)$ But this means that $q_i \notin N_r(p)$. So no point from $X$ except $p$ can lie in $N_r(p)$, so $N_r(p)=\{p\}$ is a witnessing ball that shows that $x$ is not a limit point of $X$.

Comment: One thing I always wondered about such arguments, Is the interval $r$ empty?

Comment: @user460345 $r$ is a positive real number, there are no intervals here. $r$ empty is a nonsense statement.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, thanks. I guess my book assumes $X = \mathbb R$ implicitly which is good enough for me. At least for now.

Comment: @user460345 it's better, eventually to learn the more abstract view. You'll meet it often later.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, given $X = \mathbb R$ and $r$ as defined by you, does it make sense to say the distance of length $r$ around $p$ **only** contains $p$ while if the smallest $d(p, q_i) = k > r,$ then the distance $r$ inside distance $k$ is empty?

Comment: @user460345 "the distance of length $r$ around $p$ contains ..." makes no sense. The proof actually only works for finite $X$, maybe for you $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, not equal (the minimum doesn't make sense otherwise).

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, let's suppose $X$ is a finite subset of reals. Does, then, all that stuff I said about $r$ above make sense?

Comment: @user460345 it's still incomprehensible.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma, at this point I'd be satisfied to know what's in the interval $r$ anywhere in $X.$ If this still makes no sense, well then nevermind :) I just have to think a bit more, I guess. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: @ Henno Brandsma,  I should've chosen your answer since you seem willing to answer questions and I've gleaned a couple interesting things from your post. Too late, though.  Let $Y$ be a finite metric space with $ q \in Y.$ Does it make sense to say (a) every neighborhood of $q$ is in $Y,$ (b) every time we define a neighborhood of $q$ (for example, as you've done above) , we are designating an interval in $Y$ that contains some elements of $Y$ and excludes some others (unless the neighborhood is all of $Y$)? Please, ignore if it still makes no sense :)